# Am I correctly performing an asymptotic analysis for this algorithm, which identifies the number of unique keys for each of a collection of subsets?

Tags: algorithm, set, big-o

So, I ran into this question recently in an interview, and it's bugging me a bit. I've been programming for years, but like many self-taught folks, the force (the power of asymptotic analysis) is not strong with me. I'd like to know if I'm correctly identifying the big-Oh notation for my solution's runtime, with some caveats. The problem is essentially one that identifies when an element of a superset `S` occurs only once in one of a collection of provided subsets, `s`. Theh goal is to, for each subset, count the number of such unique occurences. We could model it ths way:

```js
const complete_set = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "car", "rocket", "house"];

const example_problem_set: OverlappingSetsByKey = {
    key1: ["apple", "ball", "cat"], // unique = 0
    key2: ["apple", "ball", "cat", "car"], // unique = 1 - car
    key3: ["rocket", "house"], // unique = 2 - rocket and house
}

const example_response: OverlappingSetsResponse = {
    key1: 0,
    key2: 1,
    key3: 2,
}
```

Here's my solution (in typescript):

```js
function getNumberOfUniqueItems(osk: OverlappingSetsByKey): OverlappingSetsResponse {

    let res = {} as OverlappingSetsResponse;

    for (let key of Object.keys(osk)) { // runs k times
        // 1. 
        // construct an array of ids that represent all *other* ids 
        let otherIds:string[] = [];
        for (let innerKey of Object.keys(osk)) { // runs k times
            if (innerKey == key) continue; // skip the current key
            let innerIds = osk[innerKey];
            for (let id of innerIds) // runs i times
                if (!otherIds.includes(id)) otherIds.push(id);
        }

        // 2. 
        // filter values from osk[key] that are in the shared array
        let uniqueValues:string[] = osk[key].filter(id => !otherIds.includes(id)); // at least i times
        
        // 3. 
        // store just the length in res
        res[key] = uniqueValues.length;
    }

    return res;
}
```

For a language agnostic description:

- For each subset `s`

  - Create a new list `L`, representing the ids found in every *other* subset
  - Iterate over every other subset `s'`

    - Iterate over every value in `s'`

      - Add that value to `L`, if not already present
  - Filter `s` such that it only contains values not found in `L`
  - Return the length of the filtered `s`

Given the notes above, my asymptotic analysis was something along these lines:

1. The outer loop runs `k` times, for `k` keys
2. The first inner loop runs `k` times for each key,
3. The second inner loop runs `i` times, where `i` is the size of the superset
4. The filter operation has to run somewhere around `i` times, though I'm not sure of the performance of `filter` and `includes`, I'd be willing to bet this operation is `i**2`.

Which leads me to... `k + k*i + k+k + k*k+i`
Or ... `(i)k^2 + k^2 + ki + k`

Which, if the number of keys (different subsets) were the problem size, would make it such that `f(n) = O(n^2)`, plain and simple, because the `k^2` term will outgrow the others, and we ignore multiplicative constances, so I'll drop the `i`.

***I'm not satisfied with this, for two reasons:***

1. I have nested loops of `depth=3`, so intuitively, `O(n^2)` doesn't *feel* appropriate. Again, that's me leaning on my intuitive reading of the code.
2. The *size* of the problem is not well described by `k`. In fact, this seems like a multi-dimensional problem size, defined by (1) the size of the superset and (2) the number of subsets we're comparing.

The above makes me want to say that `f(k, i) = O(i * k^2)` when describing its resource consumption. Can one use multivariate expressions in big-Oh notation? Can you have multiple factors that contribute to `n`, affecting its runtime differently? If my notation is correct, why wouldn't the lower-order term be ignored in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the complete set has `n` items. For complexity analysis, we take the max possible for every list/set unless we have special, known restrictions. This means each subset in `OverlappingSetsByKey` could have `n` items as well. You've used `k` for the number of subsets in `OverlappingSetsByKey`.

So far, we have `O(k^2)`:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(osk))
  for (let innerKey of Object.keys(osk))
```

Let's add the subset logic, `O(n^2 + n^2)`:

```
...
  ...
    // There can be n items in a subset
    for (let id of osk[innerKey])
      // `includes` can iterate over n items
      if (!otherIds.includes(id)) {
        otherIds.push(id);
      }
      
    // The subset can contain n items
    osk[key].filter(id =>
      // `includes` can iterate over n items
      !otherIds.includes(id));
```

All together `O(k^2 * 2 * n^2) = O(k^2 * n^2`.